# WFS, ArcGIS Server 10.2 and WFS maxFeatures?

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, arcgis-10.2, memory

I'm experiencing intermittent 'out of server memory' errors on 
our public ArcGIS Server 10.2 server.

From what I can glean from the OGC documentation the server side
maxfeatures parameter was only available in the WFS 1.1.0 spec but
not 1.0.0

I suspect that our server is temporarily being overwhelmed by WFS 1.0.0 requests.

IE some feature types have in excess of 90,000 records

We need WFS capability on our services for integration with another system. The other
system is being coded to perform WFS 1.1.0 requests so the maxfeatures will apply.

Is there any way I can 'turn off' WFS 1.0.0 support in ArcGIS Server 10.2 without turning
1.1.0 off?

The only thing ESRI support and I came up with was to create a custom getcapabilities
xml version 1.0.0 file and delete all feature types in that minus the one with least records...

Regards,
Richard